# Cannot create region dynamically from client in Geode

Tags: geode

- I want to create a new region from client which does not exist on the server.
- Followed the Official doc **Creating Regions Dynamically**, there's only server-side functions but no client-side code.
- I try to call the **CreateRegionFunction** by client cache but get an error:
  **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: operation is not supported on a client cache**

Here's my client-side code:

```
ClientCache cache = new ClientCacheFactory()
    .addPoolLocator("<hostname>", 10334)
    .set("log-level", "WARN")
    .create();
Execution execution2 = FunctionService.onServers(cache);
ArrayList argList = new ArrayList();
argList.add("region_new");
RegionAttributes attr = new AttributesFactory().create();
argList2.add(attr);
Function function = new CreateRegionFunction();
FunctionService.registerFunction(function);
Object result = execution.setArguments(argList).execute(function).getResult();
```

Answer (score 1):

I would really recommend that you use either use `gfsh` OR [spring data geode](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/current/reference/html/#bootstrap-annotation-config) to create the region.

If you want to use the function to create the regions on the server, the following steps are required:

1. Create a jar that contains `CreateRegionFunction` and `CreateRegionCacheListener` from the [docs page](https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/11/developing/region_options/dynamic_region_creation.html).
2. Ensure that the jar is available to the server (either using `gfsh deploy` command OR by adding the jar to the classpath while starting the server.
3. Remove the following line from your client code: `FunctionService.registerFunction(function);`
4. Then run your client code.

Again, I think it would be much easier for you to use `gfsh` to create the region.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I solved the problem by modify the functions in official doc.
As the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

- In the Official doc there's a `CreateRegionFunction` in which there is

  `public CreateRegionFunction() {
      this.cache = CacheFactory.getAnyInstance();
      this.regionAttributesMetadataRegion = 
  createRegionAttributesMetadataRegion();
  }`
- In this way, if you create a `clientcache` and run the function using `execution.execute` as I did, the function will not run on the server.
- Then I found that the Official doc's method seems to be out-of-date. It seems there's no need to create a `_regionAttributesMetadata`. We can create a region directly as below:

  `public void execute(FunctionContext context) {
      cache = CacheFactory.getAnyInstance();
      regionAttributesMetadataRegion = 
  createRegionAttributesMetadataRegion();
      ArrayList arguments = (ArrayList) context.getArguments();
      String regionName = (String) arguments.get(0);
      PartitionAttributes partition = new 
  PartitionAttributesFactory().setColocatedWith("/region1").create();
      Region region = cache.createRegionFactory().setDataPolicy(DataPolicy.PERSISTENT_PARTITION 
  ).setPartitionAttributes(partition).create(regionName);
      // Return status
      context.getResultSender().lastResult(region.toString());
  }`

Comment: When you try to scale the geode cluster by adding additional servers, you want those new servers to create the regions that were already created in existing servers. The way to achieve that is using the __regionAttributesMetadata region along with the CreateRegionCacheListener on that region.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like that I misunderstood the meaning of "Create region dynamically".

Answer (score 0):

The reason you were getting the error is because you were calling `CacheFactory.getAnyInstance()` and `createRegionAttributesMetadataRegion()` in the constructor. 
You call the the `CreateRegionFunction()` constructor from your client, right. So you get the instance of your `ClientCache`, not `Cache`. After that, you try to create a `RegionAttributesMetadataRegion` in your ClientCache, which is not supported.

Once you moved that in the `execute` function, it doesn't get called in the constructor (which is in your client), and it only gets called in the execute in your server. I'm guessing that's the mistake in the Geode docs.

PS: thanks for your post. I was about to give up on dynamic region creation until I found that it works for someone else.